# Count arrays with values in state in React

Tags: reactjs

I currently have the following state:

```
this.state = {
  selectProduct: [somearrayValues],
  quantityProduct: [],
  colorsProduct: [somearrayValues],
  stockProduct: [somearrayValues],
  turnaroundProduct: [],
  coatingProduct: [],
  attributeProduct: [somearrayValues],
  attributeMetaProduct: [somearrayValues],
}
```

I do a fetch call to fill up the arrays with the needed data.
From here I need to get a count of Arrays that actually contain a value.  I'm lost as how to accomplish this.

I first was trying to get to the state with a for each loop but I haven't even got passed this point:

```
let dropdownArrays = ...this.state;
dropdownArrays.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

This gives me an error when babel attempts to compile.
I then tried the below, which returns nothing.

```
let dropdownArrays = [...this.state];
dropdownArrays.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

I know I'm missing it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: objects do not implement the iterable protocol. you have to do something like `Object.values(this.state).forEach(current => { ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `Object#values()` method to access the array objects (ie the values) of the `state`, and then count the number of non-empty arrays like so:

```js
// Pre-filled arrays with some values. This solution would work
// regardless of the values you populate the arrays with
const state = {
  selectProduct: [1,2,3,4],
  quantityProduct: [],
  colorsProduct: [4,5,6,7],
  stockProduct: [1,2],
  turnaroundProduct: [],
  coatingProduct: [],
  attributeProduct: [6,7,8,9,10],
  attributeMetaProduct: [5,4,6],
}

const result = Object.values(state)
.filter((array) => array.length > 0)
.length;

console.log('Number of arrays in state with values (non-empty)', result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because state is an object, you instead could use a couple different options. You could do

this.state.values, which will return an array of the values in state.

```
this.state.values.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Or you could use this.state.entries, which will return an array of the key, value.

```
this.state.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    // expected output [key, value]
});
```

Lastly as you appear to already be attempting to use destructuring, you can also destructure the result.

```
this.state.entries.forEach(function([key, value]) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
Object.entries(...this.state)[1].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.length, 0)
```

Bear in mind that to use `...this.state` you need https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread

Answer (score 0):

```js
var state = {
  selectProduct: [1,2,3,4],
  quantityProduct: [],
  colorsProduct: [4,5,6,7],
  stockProduct: [1,2],
  turnaroundProduct: [],
  coatingProduct: [],
  attributeProduct: [6,7,8,9,10],
  attributeMetaProduct: [5,4,6],
}

// In your code replace state with this.state
let emptyArrays = Object.values(state).reduce(
  (acc, current)=> ( !current.length? ++acc: acc),
  0
)

console.log(emptyArrays)
```